# Dynamic links linking to root domain

Tags: php, mysql

I am building a site directory and I am having some trouble linking up to sites..

The directory currently stores the site domain in a table and calls it through a foreach loop listing 25 separate domains on the page, but when I click on the links I am greeted with

localhost/directory (my site root) /linkeddomain.com

Rather than just displaying linkeddomain.com

I put `http://www.` in front of the array call

```
href='http://www.".$row['siteurl']."
```

However this is useless for production because if anyone enters into their domain `http://www.theirdomain.com` it will come out as `http://www.http://www.theirdomain.com`

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Thanks in advance

Luke

Comment: Sanitise and normalise the domain names when you are supplied them, you can then use them in a more uniform manner. The PHP functions parse_url and filter_var should get you on your way.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the base URL is always the *full* URL, including the scheme and a subdomain (if applicable).

So:

```
$base_url = "http://livesite.com";
$base_url = "http://localhost/john/customerX";
$base_url = "https://secure.livesite.com";
```

If all your links are prefix by the base URL you should be fine.

Note that in all URLs I left off the trailing `/`. You can chose to include it, just make sure you always do it in the same way - have a clear **normalized** form.

Answer (score 0):

You can just check to see if you need to add http to the url or not.

```
if(!preg_match("^https?://", $url)){
    $url .= "http://" . $url;
}
```

That will only add it if it is needed.